# Oracle PL/SQL - Conexão com Webserver SEFAZ

Tags: web-service, nfe, pl-sql, certificado-digital, oracle12c

Alguém aqui já conseguiu estabelecer contatar e autenticar os servidores da SEFAZ (NF-e ou Reinf) através de PL/SQL com Oracle Wallet?

Pelas ultimas semanas tenho tentado estabelecer contato com  estes webservers, primeiro com Oracle  11, e depois com o Oracle 12, mas não tenho conseguido.

Os últimos erros que tem ocorrido são

> **ORA-29024**: Falha de validação de certificado

Mas estou utilizando um certificado gerado recentemente e seguido os diversos tutoriais existentes na internet.

A questão é como trata-se de serviços da SEFAZ, com chave pública do contribuinte, não sei se é limitação do Oracle com a tecnologia da SEFAZ, se é erro na criação do wallet, ou algum outro motivo.

Neste momento do projeto, o requisito ainda se mantém para conectar desta forma. Gostaria de exaurir todas as possibilidades, ou pelo obter todos os argumentos contra, de conexão via Oracle.

Se alguém conseguiu conectar desta forma, poderia passar um passo-a-passo ou pelo menos algumas dicas de como proceder?